# Administrative Review result mail - Visa Tier 4 Student

Tags: visas, uk, study

I just received an email for my Administrative Review (AR) result (Tier 4 visa) from the AR team but I am so confused by their decision. I don't know exactly whether my application is overturned or upheld. Please explain their decision.

Mail:

> Title: AR overturned GWF04.....  Dear T
>
> GWF04....
>
> Date: 24/01/2018
>
> Name: T Our Reference: 7......
>
> Email address provided with the application: @GMAIL.COM   Email
>   address provided with the AR request: as above
>
> Dear Mr T,
>
> Administrative Review under the Points Based System (PBS)
>
> You applied for entry clearance to the United Kingdom under Tier 4 of
>   the Points Based System. Your application failed to meet the
>   qualifying criteria and was refused on 03/01/2018. Your request for
>   Administrative Review was received by this office on 10/01/2018.
>
> I have reviewed your application and I am satisfied that the decision
>   to refuse you entry clearance was incorrect. Details of my decision
>   are on the back of this letter (Points Summary Document).
>
> The decision making centre in Sheffield will be in contact shortly
>   regarding next steps.
>
> Yours sincerely,
>
> HJ Administrative Reviewer
>
> Points Summary Document
>
> Name: T Our  Reference: 7.... CAS Points Claimed Original Points
>   awarded AR Points awarded    30 0 30
>
> ECO Comment:
>
> You have claimed 30 points for your CAS but have failed to provide
>   Bachelors Degree in Economics from the University of Economics..... I
>   am not satisfied that you have provided the specified documents as
>   required under Appendix A of the Immigration Rules. I am therefore not
>   satisfied that you achieved 30 points under Appendix A and meet the
>   requirements for entry clearance as a Tier 4 (General) Student. I
>   therefore refuse your application under paragraph 245ZV (b) of the
>   Immigration Rules.
>
> ECM Comment: I note your document checklist, as stated by you in
>   your review request, stated your Bachelors Degree was submitted at the
>   time of application. I also note that you have provided the
>   certificate with your review request. The document not being available
>   at assessment appears to be a scanning error. I am satisfied the
>   document was submitted and is available.
>
> Points awarded as claimed.
>
> Maintenance Points Claimed Original Points awarded AR Points awarded 
>   10 10 10
>
> ECM Comment:
>
> English language requirement – unable to show proficiency at interview
>   ECM Comment:
>
> The Entry Clearance Officer must be satisfied that the applicant is a
>   genuine student
>
> The Entry Clearance Officer has not carried out an assessment of your
>   application as a genuine student under 245ZV (k) because your
>   application already falls for refusal on other grounds, but we reserve
>   the right to carry out this assessment in any reconsideration of the
>   decision.
>
> ECM Comment: n/a, see above.
>
> General Grounds for Refusal  ECM Comment:
>
> This is an automated message - please do not respond to this email
>   address as incoming mail is not answered. UKVI contact details can be
>   found at www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-outside-uk

Can you explain the bold line and the decision of this email? I have been waiting for their next email for a few days. I am so confused by their decision!

And what should I do if they do not send me other email or notification?
Thank you so much!

Comment: It looks like your application was rejected because they thought you hadn't included your degree certificate, and they have now decided that you had. Since they didn't assess your entire application because you 'failed' at that stage I imagine they will now reassess your application as a whole. Note that questions regarding study and other long term visas are off-topic here. You should ask on [expatriates.se]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I read this, the administrative review found that the original decision was in error because you did, in fact, demonstrate that you have a bachelors degree. They have overturned that incorrect decision, and your application will go back to be evaluated now that you've been given 30 more points.

Someone from the "decision making centre in Sheffield" will contact you "shortly" to tell you what to do next. If you don't receive any kind of communication from them, you'd need to [contact UKVI](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk) and request assistance.

However, the letter notes that you did not demonstrate English language proficiency and the ECO has not yet determined whether you are a genuine student. Now that they have awarded you the points for your degree, they will check those things, along with all the other requirements, to decide whether to approve your application.